# MYSQL JOIN tables based on extracted value of field

Tags: mysql, database, string, join, extract

I am not sure how to accomplish this but I have two tables I'd like to join.

`Table 1` has a field description
Example:

```
Description  = Conv : 203RR00473 : Mr. Winchester Magnum
```

I would like to take the `name` from that `field` and match it to a `field` in `Table 2`.

`Table 2` Example:

```
animal_name = Mr. Winchester Magnum
```

So what I'm trying to do is join my Table 2 using `animal_name` and basing that join on the last part (after 2nd colon) of `Table 1.description`

I've been searching but not positive what I need to search to find the correct way to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: MySQL's function SUBSTRING_INDEX might help you out here.( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index )

Comment: Checking this now. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplifying Raymond Nijland's suggestion of SUBSTRING_INDEX

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON (animal_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Description,' : ',-1))
```

Comment: Thank you both, this worked perfectly! Exactly what I needed.